# Smarty URL for Event confirm Registration

Tags: civievent, smarty

I'm using the **Require participant approval** feature. CiviCRM 4.6.12 WordPress 4.4.2

I'm trying to send reminders to the people who hasn't already confirmed their place. Having a look at Civi's default confirmation template I can see:

```
{capture assign=confirmUrl}
   {crmURL p='civicrm/event/confirm' q="reset=1&participantId=`$participant.id`&cs=`$checksumValue`" a=true h=0 fe=1}
{/capture}
```

Which generates:

```
https://site.com/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/confirm&reset=1&participantId=123&cs=25e329e8ccb2ac583e2c7f67dbf3faf8_1455187643_504.72666666667
```

In my custom template I have an API call to get the Participant ID for that event and pass it as a parameter to generate the same URL described above along with the contact's checksum but I don't get the same result:

```
https://site.com/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/confirm&reset=1&participantId=123&cs=c9d0a39ed785a0aa42fe752ce694a70f_1454935309_168
```

The later URL generated from my custom template is missing the final parameter at the end of the checksum which I guess is appended by `a=true h=0 fe=1` in smarty, what do this parameters do and how to replicate the same behavior?

I know there's **Pending participant expiration** but is not an option for this specific event.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit per Xavier's request:**

Sorry I agree, I should have been more explicit with what the actual problem is.

My problems is that the generated URL doesn't redirect to the event's Confirmation Page (ie. Confirm Registration/Cancel Registration page) so the participant can confirm their place and submit payment if applies.

This is my smarty snippet in the template:

```
{crmAPI var='participants' entity='Participant' action='get' sequential=1 event_id=$event_id contact_id=$contact_id}
{capture assign=cksum}{contact.checksum}{/capture}
{foreach from=$participants.values item=participant}
  <a href="{crmURL p='civicrm/event/confirm' q="reset=1&participantId=`$participant.id`&`$cksum`" a=true h=0 fe=1}">Confirm Place</a>
{/foreach}
```

The output URL is the same as the default template except for the bit after the **dot** at the end of the checksum

```
https://site.com/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/confirm&reset=1&participantId=123&cs=25e329e8ccb2ac583e2c7f67dbf3faf8_1455187643_504.72666666667 // default Civi template
https://site.com/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/confirm&reset=1&participantId=123&cs=c9d0a39ed785a0aa42fe752ce694a70f_1454935309_168 // my custom template
```

There's no errors, but the URL generated from my custom template redirects to the event registration profile instead of the confirmation page.
Hope that makes sense.